# My react component never displays the information from the database

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a small web app displays game information.

I am using React hooks so that the component is modern.

When this component loads, I want it to connect to the api via axios, and get the description of the game.

But when it loads, the value inside the `<GameVault />` is always null.

When I look in the database, it is not null. If I hit the api directly, it does return the game description.

My console.log is hit twice for some reason.  The first time it's null, the second time it has the needed value.

I am also not getting any errors, so I don't know why this isn't working.

Here is the code:

```
const Vault = ({ game }) => {

    const [gameText, setGameText] = useState(null);

    async function fetchGameText() {
     const response = await axios.get(`/api/gamermag/${game.id}/gameDescriptionText`);
     setGameText(response.data);
    }

    useEffect(() => {
     fetchGameText();
    }, []);
    
    console.log("gameText: ", gameText);

    const gamerValue = useMemo(() => {
    return gameText ? gameText : "";
    }, [gameText]);
    
        return (
            <GameVault value={gamerValue} />
        )
}
export default Vault;
```

Is there a way to get this to work?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked your `GameVault` component to see what it's receiving?

Answer (score 1):

You need to wait for the data to load from the server. While the data is being fetched, `gameText` will be null and when it's done fetching, it stores the response. That is why your `console.log` hit twice. The first time is the component's first render, and the second time is when the `gameText` changes its state which caused a rerender.

You need to add logic to wait for the data.

```
if(!gameText){
 return <div>loading...</div>
}
```

Comment: Do I need to add an `else`? Like `if(!gameText) { return <div>loading...</div> } else { return <GameVault value={gamerValue} />` ?

Comment: Actually I just tried that, and it is still loading an empty <gameVault>

Comment: Can you confirm if you are getting the data from the server and also in `GameVault` component

Comment: It is getting the data, but it's like it doesn't like the fact the first time the page loads the value is null.

Comment: I tried to replicate your issue with this [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gameexample-1lc5v)

Comment: Thanks. I think it might have to do with the `useMemo` statement